# What's a synonym for "ready to ship"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

We have a service that essentially dropships products for merchants, but most of them don't know what that means.

We've found better results with the phrase "ready-to-ship products", yet this too feels lacking.

Is there a better plain-language synonym or phrase for "ready-to-ship"?

Comment: "Ship on demand"?  What are you trying to say - that the merchant does not have to wait on the order to ship and that once the order is placed, it is shipped immediately?

Comment: Yes, in a sense.  The merchant does not ever handle *or even own* the inventory.  They make a sale and then the supplier ships.  We're having difficulty communicating to merchants the notion of a catalog full of such products.

Comment: Are you just looking for "*in stock*"? Or something more along the lines of "*off-the-shelf*"?

Comment: Are you actually looking for a synonym for "ready to ship"?  Do you want to differentiate between items you are not ready to ship and ones that you are?  The text of your question seems to indicate that the answer to both questions is **no** and that what you are looking for is a less niche-jargon way of describing your service.  But I am not sure, so more context would be good.

Comment: @itsbruce we want to convey to the merchants/resellers that they have access to selling products that are owned and will be shipped by others.

Comment: @DanBron is on point with this. I'm not sure how much difference is going to be made with well-known *[in stock and ready to ship](https://www.google.com/search?q="in+stock+and+ready+to+ship")*.

Comment: A bit long, but *"Ready and waiting for your customers' orders."*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an inverse of the word "consignment"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210513/is-there-an-inverse-of-the-word-consignment)

Comment: I'm an Amazon employee who works with packaging and think about these distinctions a lot. Is this product ready to ship in the sense that I could throw it into a UPS truck immediately, or is it simply available to be ordered?

Comment: What about 'dropships'? What is _that_? I've never heard it before. "ready-to-shiop" sounds like it means something, but is that what dropship means? Can you explain more what the whole concept means (without using the word "ready to ship" or "dropship").

Answer (score 2):

'Drop-ship' means to ship directly from the wholesaler to the customer. I have no idea what you are asking. That's what the expression means. If you don't know what it means, maybe that's why the retailer is confused.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the technology sector where we use terms like "software as a service", these terms come to my mind:

- ***inventory as a service***: Customer subscribes to a service that gives them access to inventory (as opposed to buying and storing inventory for themselves).
- ***inventory in the cloud***: The inventory is not kept on customer premises, but in some vaguely described facility that is managed for them (your customer does not need to care about from where the inventory is sourced, the receiver will believe the source was from your customer).
- ***inventory on demand***: The inventory is provided as soon as it is requested (the inventory is always in stock).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of something along the lines of "reserved," "contracted" or "ordered." Those don't strictly mean ready to ship, but perhaps they give you a way to indicate that certain items are set aside for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Shippable comes to mind. A shippable product is a product that's ready to/can be shipped/delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Not upstanding the question. But "Allocated" is the term that we use when the item has been ordered but not ship (dropped or to Distributor).

Comment: I don't think this term describes the state that the OP is after.